# Why Olympics don't follow exact time to conduct a game?

Tags: olympics, media, schedule

According to the Olympic schedule, the Women's Badminton semifinal between Nozomi and Sindhi should occur at 1700 IST. However, this game seems to have been held hours later, at 2030 IST.

Why would a game in the Olympics not be held at the time it is scheduled for?

Comment: Welcome to SE.Sport. Could you please add more info? Have you checked it on official website?

Comment: Please let us know the name of your country and broadcasting company, There is a possibility that the broadcasting company in your country was so poor that it didn't pay the premium for a live broadcast.

Comment: Vote to leave open. The question is clear if one bothers to try: *the game was scheduled for time X, but apparently played at time Z. Why would the game be played out of schedule?* to which Ale has already given an (insufficiently evidenced, but still potentially viable) answer. The fact that OP might simply be wrong in fact, doesn't make it an invalid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all major badminton tournaments, not just the Olympics, they only use a limited number of courts for major games (e.g semifinals and finals). As a result the scheduling works in a way for example on one day, on a specific court:

- Women's Doubles Semi Final #1 4pm
- Men's Doubles Semi Final #1 5pm
- Women's Singles Semi Final #1 6pm
- Men's Singles Semi Final #1 7pm
- Mixed Doubles Semi Final #1 8pm

Here apart from the first match, Women's Doubles Semi Final #1, all other times are estimates, and the matches may begin earlier or later than anticipated, accordingly with when the previous match finishes.

This is known as the "Order of Play" and each match will be numbered. Often the time estimates may not even be shown (apart for the first match), just the order in which the matches will proceed.

This is the reason why the game you wanted to watch did not quite appear at the scheduled time.

Answer (score 0):

On [official page](https://www.rio2016.com/en/badminton-womens-singles-semi-final-bd-2) the starting time is 16:00 BRT (Brasilia Time).

Maybe abroad there is possible that media scheduling move the streaming because of internal reasons

Comment: I read your comment, but what time is it in India when it is 16:00 BRT? The OP says the semifinal **should occur at 1700 IST** and it is 8:30 am BRT. Don't you think something is wrong with the question?